# How do I remove linebreaks ONLY if they occur inside html tags?

Tags: python, html-parsing

Sorry, another python newbie question. I have a string:

```
my_string = "<p>this is some \n fun</p>And this is \n some more fun!"
```

I would like:

```
my_string = "<p>this is some fun</p>And this is \n some more fun!"
```

In other words, how do I get rid of '\n' **only** if it occurs inside an html tag?

I have:

```
my_string = re.sub('<(.*?)>(.*?)\n(.*?)</(.*?)>', 'replace with what???', my_string)
```

Which obviously won't work, but I'm stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: don't try and parse XML or HTML with regex it won't work, use a dedicated parser then you can regex out the `\n` from the content and write it back out.

Comment: Python regexes are not really powerful enough for this, unless you're willing to cut some corners. For example, if you'd be content with "remove a linebreak if the next HTML tag is a closing tag, and don't care about comments", then you might have a chance with regex.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I don't know how you concluded that this is a duplicate of this question.  It's not, because this question isn't explicitly about regular expressions, and it also expresses a specific problem about HTML processing that the asker wants addressed.  Please don't mark duplicates unless the question really is a duplicate.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: maybe regex is not the way to go but your link doesn't answer my question: how to remove linebreaks inside HTML tags. I think you and some of the others got sidetracked by focusing not on the original question

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: The question is, "how do I remove line breaks from HTML?" and you are claiming that the answer is, "do not use regex for HTML".  That doesn't answer the question.  The fact that the answers and comments agree with the recommendation does not change the fact that "do not use regex" is not an answer, and this question is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Did you read the answer to what I marked as duplicate? It says "do not use regex, have you tried using a parser instead?". Exactly what your answer says.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: My answer is very short, but that is an unfair truncation of it.  Parsing the HTML only solves half the problem.  I've at least given the asker the courtesy of using the terminology to point towards the rest of the solution, "walk the tree" will help you find the necessary interfaces in the html5lib or Beautiful Soup documentation.  Hairr's excellent answer is also not a copy of the answers from that other question.

Comment: @DietrichEpp If you disagree with the close vote and think I've violated any policies, please flag it to a moderator. Discussing it here is not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using BeautifulSoup (`bs4`), this will allow you to parse XML tags and pages.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> my_string = "<p>this is some \n fun</p>And this is \n some more fun!"
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_string)
>>> p = soup.p.contents[0].replace('\n ','')
>>> print p
```

This will pull out the new line in the p tag.  If the content has more than one tag, `None` can be used as well as a for loop, then gathering the children (using the `tag.child` property).

For example:

```
>>> tags = soup.find_all(None)
>>> for tag in tags:
...    if tag.child is None:
...        tag.child.contents[0].replace('\n ', '')
...    else:
...        tag.contents[0].replace('\n ', '')
```

Though, this might not work exactly the way you want it (as web pages can vary), this code can be reproduced for your needs.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are a bad match for HTML.  Don't do it.  See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Instead, use an HTML parser.  Python ships with [html.parser](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), or you can use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/).  All you have to do then is walk the tree and remove line breaks.

Comment: beautifulsoup is really what you want to do, especially if it's for arbitrary HTML documents (especially of arbitrary quality)

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Well, it depends on where the documents are coming from.  I personally use html5lib when I'm using Python for authoring web content — the semantics of errors (and abbreviations) in HTML5 are more well-known than those in Beautiful Soup.